# Associations, File Not Found exception

Tags: java, exception, associations

when I add associations to my project I'm getting the file not found exception.
If I comment those lines, the applications works fine.

Klient.java

```
Set<Przewoz> przewozy = new HashSet<Przewoz>();


@OneToMany
public void setPrzewozy(Set przewozy) {
    this.przewozy = przewozy;
}

@OneToMany
public Set<Przewoz> getPrzewozy() {
    return przewozy;
}

@OneToMany
public void dodajPrzewoz(Przewoz przewoz) {
    przewoz.setKlient(this);
    przewozy.add(przewoz);
}
```

Przewoz.java

```
@ManyToOne
public Klient getAklient(){
    return aklient;
}
@ManyToOne
public void setKlient(Klient aklient) {
    this.aklient = aklient;
}
```

[image]